# Retrieving roles from back-end without jwt

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot, security

My goal is to provide the user roles from the backend ,for example if the user wants to see my ressources in my backend he can login with google and the angular app takes the access token retrieved from google authorization server and send it back to my ressource server and the backend checks the token but the problem is the access token of provided by google doesn't claims named roles so basically I should retrieve roles from the database and then send it back to the front end ,my problem is on the front side because even I secured the backend by modifying the security context authoroties I still have problem in the front because it's not secure if someone modified the reponse ha can change his roles what should I do

```
package com.example.ressource_server.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.oauth2ResourceServer( r-> r.jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")));
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated());
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer, but not necessarily the simplest implementation would be to implement your own kind of login wrapper.

Assuming your user has logged in and you have a shiny token that passes all validation, you could use that as your apps own login credentials (stick with me).

Using JWT or cookies or sessions or <insert any number of server/ui secure comms words you want> you can set up your own system that doesn't actually use the 3rd party token at all.

I personally use JWTs - that would work well for this; if you really wanted, you could include the 3rd party token as an extra claim in the JWT payload if you have need of using it in the future.

To be honest, though, once a 3rd party has said the user has successfully logged in, there's no reason to worry about using that token in the rest of your app unless you plan on using it to do other things with that 3rd party on the users behalf.

Thus, use the token - rather than the users direct credentials - as proof of login and go ahead and populate your own JWT (or something else) and use that.

Alternatively, do it yourself and generate some signed value that you attach and check in your headers when communicating based on the token. If the claims have been altered, the signature won't pass validation and you know it's been tampered with. (This is, essentially, what JWT is/does - a data set that's been signed so you know if any of the values have been modified).